# How can i get the all running apps information

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing one application.In that i have written the below code for getting the list of  background running applicaiton.

```
- (NSArray *)runningProcesses {
@try {
 int mib[4] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_ALL, 0};
    size_t miblen = 4;

    size_t size;
    int st= sysctl(mib, miblen, NULL, &size, NULL, 0);

    struct kinfo_proc * process = NULL;
    struct kinfo_proc * newprocess = NULL;

    do {

        size += size/ 10;
        newprocess = realloc(process, size);

        if (!newprocess){

            if (process){
                free(process);
            }

            return nil;
        }

        process = newprocess;
        st = sysctl(mib, miblen, process, &size, NULL, 0);

    } while (st == -1 && errno == ENOMEM);

    if (st == 0){

        if (size % sizeof(struct kinfo_proc) == 0){
            int nprocess = size / sizeof(struct kinfo_proc);

            if (nprocess){

                NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                BOOL Found=NO;

                for (int i = nprocess - 1; i >= 0; i--){


                    NSString * processID = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", process[i].kp_proc.p_pid];
                    NSString * processName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", process[i].kp_proc.p_comm];
[array addObject:processName]; 
 [processID release];
                    [processName release];
                    //[array addObject:dict];
                    //[dict release];
                }
 free(process);
                 return [array autorelease];
             }
         }
     }

     return nil;
 }
@catch (NSException *ex)
{
    NSLog(@"Exception is %@",ex);
    return nil;
}
```

}

It gives the apps information.For example, it gives the applications information like templerun,skype,Angrybirds etc.
After some time when i run this code,this given the apps list as skype only.But remaining apps are appeared in mobile background running apps list.
So please tell me how to get the all running apps list from the mobile background running applications list.

Answer (score 0):

Its because background application which you think running in background are actually not running in background. They are just icons of apps.

Each apps on the device are running  in the background just for 10 minz. After that ios killed those thread and just show icons.

Try to run any app and than push it in background, quickly check your running apps list in your app, you will find it there. But after 10 minz you will not find it there.

Try it. And let me know am I right?

Comment: It's not just after 10 mins, it's whenever the OS needs those resources. Could be a few seconds, could be hours...